# EL expression not being evaluated inside <c:if> tag

Tags: jsp, oracle-adf, jspx

I have difficulty evaluating `mod` expressions in `<c:if>` statement.

```
<af:forEach begin="0" end="2" step="1" var="col" varStatus="columnStatus">

    <c:set var="colIndex" value="${columnStatus.index}" scope="page" />

    <trh:cellFormat width="33%" valign="top" halign="center" id="cf1">        
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl4" layout="vertical" halign="center">
            <af:iterator id="i1"
                    value="#{pageFlowScope.SkillsMatcherBean.candidateList}"
                    rows="#{pageFlowScope.SkillsMatcherBean.candidateListSize}"
                    var="row"
                    varStatus="rowStatus"
                    first="#{columnStatus.index}">
                <c:if test="${rowStatus.index mod 3 == '${columnStatus.index}'}">
                    <af:group id="g1">
                        <af:outputText value="index" id="ot6"/>
                        <af:outputText value=" #{rowStatus.index}" id="ot2"/>
                        <af:outputText value="end" id="ot7"/>
                        <af:outputText value=" #{columnStatus.index}" id="ot3"/>
                        <af:outputText value="count" id="ot13"/>
                        <af:outputText value=" #{rowStatus.index % 3}" id="ot5"/>
                        <af:outputText value="#{test}" id="ot1"/>
                        <af:spacer width="10" height="5" id="s1"/>
                    </af:group>
                </c:if>
            </af:iterator>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
    </trh:cellFormat>
</af:forEach>
```

I have two iterator loops with the outer-loop `varStatus` variable as `"columnStatus"` and inner loop `varStatus` variable as `"rowStatus"`.

`columnStatus` spans from 0 - 2

`rowStatus` spans from 1 - 18

In the above expression, `rowStatus.index mod 3` always evaluates to `0`. I have tried with `%` and `mod`.

I am using `Jdev 11.1.1.6`.

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: @Rhiya Check if this logic of using `first="#{columnStatus.index}">` is proper. Also, `${(rowStatus.index mod 3) eq columnStatus.index}` can also be tried.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the af:iterator tag. It stamps its children, which means that it does not evaluate expressions within. use af:forEach instead of af:iterator. Note that the difference is that af:iterator works with collections whereas af:forEach works with list.

Also note that instead of using c:if you can use the af:switcher to toggle the visual state of a group of components. JSTL and JSF doon't have the same request behavior, which is why any native JSF component is preferred

Frank

Answer (score 0):

While Frank functionally is right, performance wise he is not: af:forEach will generate a UI component for every iteration, and af:switcher will include the subtree even when rendered is false. So his suggestions increase the size of the UI tree. In general, there is a correlation between UI tree size and response size for EVERY action in that page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that that EL expression will always be false , becasue it compares a number to a string inside quotes.

you should try the following:

```
  <c:if test="${rowStatus.index mod 3 == columnStatus.index}">
```